# How can i get position an element in vue-cli 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I need to get an element position in vue-cli3. I tried somethings. But I cant make it. I Shared it below this. Anyone give me some suggestion? I want to get value in mounted hook for this. I cant use target or MouseOver events. Thanks from now.

```
this.$refs.elementRef.getBoundingClientRect()
```

Comment: what type is your element? a button?

Comment: Any element div, input, button like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of an element using Vue **ref** by doing the following:

```
this.$refs.elementRef.$el.getBoundingClientRect() // .top or .left etc...
```

More info about `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` @ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div ref="elementRef"></div>
```

Script

```
this.$refs["elementRef"].getBoundingClientRect();
```